# XCode 8 autolayout preview shows a broken UI while it is working well on phones

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I'm using XCode 8 and storyboard to make my UI but I am experiencing some strange issues with autolayout.

In fact, I tried something simple : centering a UILabel in my UI :

[image]

It looks good here. And to preserve the UI design, I added two constraints, like this :

[image]

with another one for the spacing between the UILabel and the "Sign In" button.

And when I build this view in an iPhone 7, iPad etc, it looks pretty good. However, when I switch the phones in the storyboard, the UILabel is moved and it doesn't look good :

[image]

So my question is : is there an issue with the preview in XCode 8? Or is it just a normal behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orange labels in the preview mean that the label is not in its final location. You can force xcode to refresh by clicking the update frames button at the bottom of the screen, next to the constraints tie-fighter icon.